# Indian rupee symbol

Tags: html, internet-explorer, unicode

The indian rupee symbol Unicode U+20B9 (HTML: ₹) renders correctly in latest version of IE/ firefox but it doesn't it render in IE8

Is this related to system font or the internet explorer?

Comment: The Rupee symbol isn't in the ASCII set. Don't you mean the Unicode code-point instead?

Comment: Yup.  U+20B9 in Unicode 6. See http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U20A0.pdf for a fuller list.

Comment: @David: I have updated the question, I was refering to Unicode symbol only

Comment: Not sure if this helps but try &#8377;

Comment: Html &#8377; works good in my laptop which has latest version of IE/ firefox but not sure why it is not rendering in other system which has IE8. Just wanted to verify if it is the problem related to IE or system font

Comment: @Idris, are you sure the system that runs IE8 has an appropriate font installed? (I'm asking because my current system has a good set of global fonts, including Devanagari, but still cannot render `U+20B9`.)

Comment: @Hamidi: The system that runs IE8 has only minimal font. So this isssue because of the system font?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Empty rectanglar box is displayed instead of the rupee symbol in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37643675/empty-rectanglar-box-is-displayed-instead-of-the-rupee-symbol-in-html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all fonts have this symbol. So if you don't specify a font explicitly, the browsers try to use a fallback-font to display things. And IE may use a different fallback-font.

I'm not sure if you can call this a problem with IE. It could be a font problem: the font which IE tries to use, may incorrectly tell the system it can display the sign, while it actually can't.

So if you know which fonts can display the rupee, specify one of those fonts in the HTML for it.

Comment: @juanpastas You can test if the symbol you want is present in a font by displaying the font in the character selector utility (kcharselect, charmap.exe etc) and just checking visually if it's there. But if you don't know which fonts to test, I'd suggest starting with the largest one...

Comment: @juanpastas Oh... after reading your answer, the solution is of course to use [this font](http://cdn.webrupee.com/WebRupee.V2.0.ttf).

Comment: I tested with the font I mentioned in IE9 and did not work for me, although for others it has worked. Will try with the font you mention, @ don't work for me neither in SO, this message is for Mr Lister

Comment: The @ is removed if you comment to the person who posted the answer (or the question), since they get a notification anyway.

Comment: The practical problem is limited font support to this relatively new character. Although even Arial is mentioned in the [Fileformat.info font support page](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20b9/fontsupport.htm), this applies only to very new versions of Arial. The safest bet is to use a suitable free font, like a DejaVu font, as a downloadable font, via `@font-face`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm too late but I think this is the best solution visit http://fontawesome.io/icons/