# WebRupee is not working

Tags: javascript, css

In my website I have used the new rupee sign for indicating the rupees.  Following is my code:

As a script i've used  "http://cdn.webrupee.com/js and I've also used following:

```
<span class="WebRupee">Rs.</span> 116,754.00
```

As a CSS I have used..

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.webrupee.com/font">
```

It was working fine... but during last few days it's not working.  Even it seems to be that the website is no longer available.  I cannot indicate the rupees by the symbol.

Is their any substitution for showing the symbol? Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: Since it's free to use, you could download the js and use it locally. I found it cached here: http://web.archive.org/web/20130808084012/http://cdn.webrupee.com/js

Comment: @Jayz, I’m afraid the JavaScript code alone does not suffice, as it seems to use a style sheet that is not available online.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Indian rupee symbol](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11741931/indian-rupee-symbol)

Comment: There are several older questions on the Indian rupee symbol. Some answers present different ways of using it. You can e.g. enter “₹” as such on a web page (when using a suitable editor and using the UTF-8 encoding), but then the problem is how to make browsers find a font for it.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela, you can get the stylesheet from the same site, here it is: http://web.archive.org/web/20130808052526/http://cdn.webrupee.com/font

Comment: @Jayz, and then you would need to track down the font files too. It would turn out that the code is based on a kludgery that uses a font where the Indian rupee sign is assigned to code positions for some Ascii characters.

Answer (score 7):

You can use this code for the new Rupee symbol:  `&#8377;`

It renders like this:  ₹

The older Rupee symbol is also available using the same technique, but with a different code: `&#8360;`

It renders like this:  ₨

No special stylesheet is needed, but your page will need to use the UTF-8 character set.  I tried the address you provided for the stylesheet and it's giving a 404 error.  That site may not be available anymore.

Comment: It should work for any browser that supports Unicode 6.0.  I don't have a list of all the applicable browsers, but it should be easy to test in any given browser.

Comment: Use of UTF-8 is not needed for this. The “new Rupee symbol”, INDIAN RUPEE SIGN, is supported by a few fonts only, and it will not be displayed unless the system has a font containing it and the browsers knows to use that font. Support to Unicode does *not* require an ability to display all Unicode characters. So while the approach is theoretically correct, it is practically insufficient.

Answer (score 2):

You can download the complete working css with fonts here:

http://krmaurya.com/codelibrary/rupee-symbol.zip

Answer (score 0):

To ensure maximum compatibility I think you should use FontAwesome. To use FontAwesome just add the following cdn in your head section its free.

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Now all you have to do is add this for your rupee symbol

```
<span class="fa fa-inr"></span>
```

The above code will give you the rupee symbol. And since FontAwesome has lots of cool icon you can use for your website.

For more information you can visit the site http://fontawesome.io/icons/#currency