# Rupee Symbol ₹ is not dispaying in IE8 Browser?

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer-8

Html + IE8 + jquery

I am giving one Range price slider for that i need to show Rupee currency symbol (₹).it is coming fine in chrome and mozilla but ie8 some garbage is coming.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Function for multiselect on search result page
var prefix = '<%= prefix %>';
// $(function () {
  var min_a = 100;
  var max_a = 1000;
  var prefix = '<%= prefix %>';
    $('#' + prefix +'slider-container').slider({
      range: true,
      min: min_a,
      max: max_a,
      values: [min_a, max_a],
      create: function() {
        $("#"+ prefix + "amount").val("₹" + min_a + " - ₹" + max_a); // Rupee Symbol is not displaying.
      },
      slide: function (event, ui) {
        $("#"+ prefix + "amount").val("₹ " + ui.values[0] + " - ₹ " + ui.values[1]); // Rupee Symbol is not displaying.
      }
    })
</script>
```

Anyone know how to show the ₹ symbol in IE 8 plz suggest.

Comment: Maybe it is better to use the unicode value: &#x20B9;

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11741931/indian-rupee-symbol

Comment: I agree with Astuanax, but if you want an overkill solution: http://webrupee.com.

Comment: ^^ Doesn't work. ^^ Opened in Firefox, Chrome, Safari on Mac. Doesn't display the symbol.

Comment: If i am giving unicode &#x20B9; unicode itself is coming. like &#x20B9;316.35